# Unable to get RegExp to work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
"br#go.span, span, a.my_a, [class=my_a]"
```

and this regex:

```
/((\.|\#|\:|(\[[a-zA-Z=]+\]))+^[()]+|[A-Za-z]+)/g
```

and I want it to return an array like this:

```
["br", "#go", ".span", "span", "a", ".my_a", "[class=my_a]"]
```

But the array I get is this:

```
["br", "go", "span", "a", "my", "a", "class", "my", "a"]
```

I have also tried:

```
/([A-Za-z]+|(\.|\#|\:|(\[[a-zA-Z=]+\])])+^(\.|\#|\:|(\[[a-zA-Z=]+\]))+)/ig
```

I have searched the Internet from top to bottom and tried many things like removing some parts and adding some parts. It's for a JavaScript library. Will you please help me?! Thanks!

I actually just want to split it at:

> '.', '#', ':' and '[*=*]' //note: * matches anything

Comment: Show us the code you're using and the results you're getting.

Comment: Should I really show the whole library code? And updated to show results I'm getting

Comment: @user3719477: No, you should show what methods you use to apply the regex on the string

Comment: I just wanted to see the code you were using with this regex.  It should be a couple lines of code max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
"br#go.span, span, a.my_a, [class=my_a]".match(/(\[[\w\W]+\])|(\w+)|(\W[\w]+)/g)
["br", "#go", ".span", " span", " a", ".my_a", "[class=my_a]"]
```

**For your Updated Query**

"I actually just want to split it at:"

'.', '#', ':' and '[=]' //note: * matches anything

try this:

```
"br#go.span, span, a.my_a, ab:c, [class=my_a]".match(/(\[[\w\W]+\])|(\.[\w]+)|(#[\w]+)|(\:[\w]+)|([\w]+)/g)
["br", "#go", ".span", "span", "a", ".my_a", "ab", ":c", "[class=my_a]"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a mistake in your regex which makes it only match the `[a-z]+` part:

> ```
> /((\.|\#|\:|(\[[a-zA-Z=]+\]))+^[()]+|[A-Za-z]+)/g
> //                            ^^
> ```

The `^` here is a [string-begin anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (which will never happen *after* that before part), instead of [negating the character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). You probably wanted

```
/((\.|\#|\:|(\[[a-zA-Z=]+\]))+[^()]+|[A-Za-z]+)/g
```

but I would suggest to include some other characters in that negated character class, such as whitespaces, commata, and all those `.#.[]` operators. For your usecase, the following regex should suffer:

```
/[.#:]?[a-z_]+|\[[a-z_=]*\]/ig
```

> I have also tried:
>
> ```
> /([A-Za-z]+|(\.|\#|\:|(\[[a-zA-Z=]+\])])+^(\.|\#|\:|(\[[a-zA-Z=]+\]))+)/ig
> //                                       ^
> ```

Um, are you using that anchor intentionally? What do you think it does?

> I actually just want to split it at '.', '#', ':' and '[=]'

I don't think you want to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string. Rather try to [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) those strings you're interested in.

```
var str = "br#go.span, span, a.my_a, [class=my_a]"
str.split(/,?\s|(?=:|#|\[|\.)/g) // (using lookahead) or
str.match(/[.#:]?[a-z_]+|\[[a-z_=]*\]/ig) // will both have the desired result
// but will deal differently with invalid strings
// and have different readability/maintainability
```